# org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "CREATE FUNCTION"

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, persistence.xml

I am trying to create a function that calculates the distance between 2 points (longitude and latitude wise) using an SQL script while running the application by specifying in the persistence.xml

```
<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-script-source"
           value="calculate_distance_function.sql" />
```

But I am having a CommandAcceptanceException and cannot figure out why.
I even tried to use

```
<property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source"
          value="calculate_distance_function.sql" />
```

but still does not work and it gives the following error.

> 00:06:21,512 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)
> Hibernate: CREATE FUNCTION CalcDistance( Lat1 DOUBLE, Long1 DOUBLE,
> Lat2 DOUBLE, Long2 DOUBLE ) RETURNS double
>
> 00:06:21,513 WARN
> [org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl]
> (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) GenerationTarget encountered
> exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "CREATE FUNCTION
> CalcDistance( Lat1 DOUBLE, Long1 DOUBLE, Lat2 DOUBLE, Long2 DOUBLE )
> RETURNS double" via JDBC Statement:
> org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error
> executing DDL "CREATE FUNCTION CalcDistance( Lat1 DOUBLE, Long1
> DOUBLE, Lat2 DOUBLE, Long2 DOUBLE ) RETURNS double" via JDBC Statement
> at
> org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
> at
> org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:440)
> at
> org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createFromScript(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:192)
> at
> org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:162)
> at
> org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:135)
> at
> org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:121)
> at
> org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:129)
> at
> org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
> at
> org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:310)
> at
> org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467)
> at
> org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:939)
> at
> org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
> at
> org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:167)
> at
> org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:125)
> at
> org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:650)
> at
> org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:209)
> at
> org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
> at
> org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
> at
> org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
> at
> org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)    at
> org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485) Caused by:
> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL
> syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
> for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1     at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:118)
> at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:95)
> at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
> at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:790)
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:675)
> at
> org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedStatement.execute(WrappedStatement.java:198)
> at
> org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
> ... 21 more

This is my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="Persistence"
        transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/tontapatt_db</jta-data-source>
        
        <class>fr.eql.ai109.tontapatt.entity.ZipCodeCity</class>
        <properties>
            <property
                name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action"
                value="create" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect"
                value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect" />
          <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-script-source"
           value="calculate_distance_function.sql" />
        <!--        <property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source"
          value="calculate_distance_function.sql" /> -->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Changing the dialect of MySQL did not help either.
If I try to open the script in MySQL workbench and run it works fine and I can see the function added. This is my SQL function script

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `CalcDistance`( Lat1 DOUBLE, Long1 DOUBLE, Lat2 DOUBLE, Long2 DOUBLE ) RETURNS double 
BEGIN 
DECLARE r INT;    
DECLARE phi1 DOUBLE;    
DECLARE phi2 DOUBLE;    
DECLARE dphi DOUBLE;    
DECLARE dlam DOUBLE;    
DECLARE a DOUBLE;    
DECLARE c DOUBLE;    
DECLARE d DOUBLE;
SET r = 6371000;    
SET phi1 = Lat1 * PI() / 180;    
SET phi2 = Lat2 * PI() / 180;    
SET dphi = ( Lat2 - Lat1 ) * PI() / 180;    
SET dlam = ( Long2 - Long1 ) * PI() / 180;   
SET a = SIN( dphi / 2 ) * SIN( dphi / 2 ) + COS( phi1 ) * COS( phi2 ) * SIN( dlam / 2 ) * SIN( dlam / 2 );    
SET c = 2 * ATAN2( SQRT( a ), SQRT( 1 - a ) );    
SET d = r * c / 1000;    
RETURN d;    
END
```

I even tried to add a delimiter before and after it.

Can someone help me out with this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try single quotes instead of backticks in first line.

Change

```
DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `CalcDistance`
```

To

```
DEFINER='root'@'localhost' FUNCTION 'CalcDistance' (Note single quotes)
```

Here is a sample from MySQL official documentation which works perfectly fine.

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'admin'@'localhost' PROCEDURE account_count()
BEGIN
  SELECT 'Number of accounts:', COUNT(*) FROM mysql.user;
END;
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood what you mean by using single quote. What I understood is to put the whole function creation statement on one line. And this worked correctly. Thanks